# Modifying Fonts with Sketch 3

Tags: sketch-app, font-design

Is is possible to modify fonts in Stetch 3? If so, what are the best techniques for doing so?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert them to curves (Type-->Convert text to outlines) and then modify the outlines of the text you converted. But you cannot change the font itself and then type out something else with the modified letters. You need font editing software for that (Fontforge, Fontlab, Glyps, etc)